# C# Update Modified properties in database

Tags: c#, database, class, design-patterns, sql-update

I have a class having a lot of properties which can be modified from outside. At the end of setting all the properties I wanted to update only the modified fields in database, so what would be the efficient way?

Eg. Let say below is my class

```
public class SomeClass {
    private int field1;
    private string field2;
    private string field3;
    private byte field4;

    public int Field1 {
        get { return field1; }
        set { field1 = value; }
    }

    public string Field2 {
        get { return field2; }
        set { field2 = value; }
    }

    public byte Field4 {
        get { return field4; }
        set { field4 = value; }
    }

    public string Field3 {
        get { return field3; }
        set { field3 = value; }
    }

    public SomeClass() { }

    public bool FillClassVariablesWithCurrentDatabaseValue() {
        //Fill the class variables with current database values
    }

    public bool UpdateModifiedFields() {
        //Only update the modified fields in database
    }
}
```

Now to know whether the field has been updated or not, I will have to add that many boolean variables in the class as below

```
public class SomeClass {
    private int field1;
    private string field2;
    private string field3;
    private byte field4;

    private bool field1Updated;
    private bool field2Updated;
    private bool field3Updated;
    private bool field4Updated;

    public int Field1 {
        get { return field1; }
        set {
            if (field1 != value) {
                field1 = value;
                field1Updated = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public string Field2 {
        get { return field2; }
        set {
            if (field2 != value) {
                field2 = value;
                field2Updated = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public byte Field4 {
        get { return field4; }
        set {
            if (field4 != value) {
                field4 = value;
                field4Updated = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public string Field3 {
        get { return field3; }
        set {
            if (field3 != value) {
                field3 = value;
                field3Updated = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public SomeClass() { }

    public bool FillClassVariablesWithCurrentDatabaseValue() {
        //Fill the class variables with current database values
    }

    public bool UpdateModifiedFields() {
        //Only update the modified fields in database
        string parameters = string.Empty;
        if (field1Updated)
            parameters += "field1=@field1";
        if (field2Updated)
            parameters += "field2=@field2";
        if (field3Updated)
            parameters += "field3=@field3";
        if (field4Updated)
            parameters += "field4=@field4";

        //code to update these fields
    }
}
```

But since my class has a lot of variables, I don't think this approach is good. Any suggestion will helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could maintain a list of properties that have changed in a

```
List<string> updatedProperties;
```

For every property that changes in the setter, add the property name to your List. Finally in the Update method, loop through the above list to create your update logic

Comment: Had think of this way too, but for that I will have to write switch cases for adding the parameter values in SqlCommand, The Update code will become messy.

Comment: The above reduces the no of variables. If you want to keep your update method clean, you can maintain a map of property names to database columns.

Comment: Will consider your answer, but waiting for really cool/awesome technique :)